# What is the use of name, id and value?

Tags: html

Why do we use the the name, id and value attributes with html elements? What are they important and how are they interpreted? What are the differences between them? I have looked at w3schools and every tutorial but I would like a simple explanation from a person.

What is the difference between just doing:

```
<form>
<input type="text" />
</form>
```

and

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="name" />
</form>
```

what are the benefits of using these attributes?

Comment: You really need to pick up a good book about HTML.

Answer (score 2):

name - passed to the server in forms

id - a unique identifier to the HTML element

value - the value of an input or textarea element

Answer (score 1):

The presence of a `name` attribute in an `input` element causes a name=value pair to be included in the form data, if the value is not empty. In the absence of such an attribute, the form field does not make any contribution to the form data.

The `id` attribute can be used to give an element a unique identifier that can be used in client-side scripting and styling. It has nothing to do with the functionality of the `name` attribute.

The `value` attribute in a text input box specifies the initial (default) content of the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Each form element in your application must save some information for you. Those are `value`.

When you want process your forms using a server-side programming language, you must point to your wanted element. Here, you need `name` to fetch your form elements values.

Also, sometimes you might need to process your form client-side or do something else on elements in your HTML document, now one way to point to them can be an `id`.

Answer (score 0):

id is usually referred to by, or used in relation to, CSS styling. name is usually referred to by data-related php or or other server-side scripting , and value is the "content" ascribed to that element, so if input value = "hello", then that is what will appear in the text input field.

Answer (score 0):

One point that the other answers don't make clear, is that the purpose of an attribute can differ depending on which element it belongs to.

So while an `id` attribute identifies an element no matter where it is, the `name` attribute serves a different purpose on the `iframe` and `object` than it does on the `meta` element, which is again different from its purpose on the submittable elements `button`, `input`,  `keygen`,  `object`, `select` and `textarea`. The `param` element and the `map` element both have `name` attributes, each for a different purpose, while the `form` element, `fieldset` element and `output` element use their name attributes for a more or less common purpose, but different from the other elements.

Similarly, the `value` attribute on the `input`, `button` and `option` elements serve similar but slightly different purposes, and the `progress` and `meter` elements share a similarly purposed `value` attribute, but each of the `param`, `li`, and `data (WHATWG HTML living standard only)` elements has a `value` attribute with a purpose dedicated to that particular element.

To understand all the purposes properly, I recommend that you at least read [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/index.html).